# Referring to professors as "Dr." in news articles and other formal wrtiting

Tags: names

In academia, "professor" is generally acknowledged as being a higher title than "doctor", as few PhD holders are professors, while basically all professors hold a PhD (RIP Freeman Dyson).  It seems most academics don't really care how they are addressed, though it is usually a mild faux pas for students to call a professor by "Dr."

In places like university websites, the title "Dr." is typically reserved for those who aren't professors, like postdocs or industry/national lab scientists.  On the other hand, in most writing outside of academic circles, especially news articles, it seems common to see professors referred to as "Dr."

For example when the New York Times is quoting some expert they usually will say "Dr.", even if it is a professor.  (E.g. "Dr. Smith, who is a professor of ..., says ... ")  I am not sure if this is done because it is a standard convention to use "Dr." for all PhD holders (and avoid "professor" perhaps because it's a job title), or just because the author doesn't know about the usual convention in academia.

Ultimately it's not a terribly important question, but I wonder what informed writers and journalists believe the "correct" way to be.  Do any official style guides say anything on this matter?

Comment: This analysis is totally wrong. People who hold a PhD (which is a *doctor of philosophy*) are given the title *doctor* by their peers and anybody else in academia. They might *also* be professors, and go by that form of address too, but there is no such thing as a higher level of respect going on here. *Doctor* is certainly not reserved for those who aren't professors.

Comment: If you want to know how to refer to an individual, ask them. Don't ask us to ask them. As for the _New York Times,_ they have editors and a style guide about stuff like that, because that's their business. But nobody else has to follow it.

Comment: @JohnLawler as I said,  most people don't really care.  And again, I'm not asking about direct address, I'm asking about general use in writing.

Comment: @JasonBassford, I'm a graduate student in physics, and my personal experience is that you *never* address a professor by "doctor".  If you don't use their first name (which is quite common these days even for undergraduates), then you use "professor".  Using "doctor" instead isn't offensive, but may be seen as weird.  In my experience "Dr." almost always is only used when speaking to posdocs or non-professor scientists.

Comment: @Aqualone I have also been to university and interacted with many professors, most of them with PhDs. My father has a PhD, and was both a professor, dean of a faculty, and then the president of a university. I have addressed professors as *doctor*, *professor*, and *mister*, *miss*, and *missus* followed by their last names. I've also called them by their first names. How they are addressed depends on context: who and how. But anybody with a PhD ***is*** a doctor. And anybody who teaches at a university ***is*** a professor. (And they also have names and regular forms of address.)

Comment: @JasonBassford, most universities hire instructors who are not granted the title of professor. Post-docs may also teach without getting the title of professor.

Comment: @ThePhoton The actual title is different from how they are normally addressed. Students will not normally know what the person's actual title or academic position is. If you know they have a PhD, they can be addressed as doctor. If nothing about their background is known, aside from the fact that they are teaching a class, they can still be called professor. And you can seldom go wrong by using their last name with the standard everyday title. That aside, students are most likely *told* by each teacher in the first class—either verbally or by having had it written on a blackboard.

Comment: @JasonBassford Perhaps it varies by region and field.  For STEM fields in both the US and UK, what I said above seems for the most part true.

Comment: @JasonBassford, that's just the principle that you rarely offend someone by calling them by a higher title than they are normally given. I wouldn't offend you by calling you "King Jason". But it wouldn't make you a king. Your claim was that "anyone who teaches at a university **is** a professor", not "may be addressed as `professor'".

Comment: @ThePhoton Indeed, if anything that statement is "totally wrong". I don't know what JasonBassford is feeling so strong about. I (OP) was genuinely curious and reporting on my real life observations.

Comment: Ask your advisor what the custom is in your discipline. It varies considerably from field to field, and you might as well follow the convention.

Comment: The *New York Times* has long had a style rule that titles (Mr., Dr., etc.) are used every time a person is mentioned; always Dr. Fauci, Mr. Biden, Mr. Trump, except in quotations and headlines.

Comment: Perhaps it's unfortunate we don't follow the German tradition in which all titles are used together, so that someone can be called, for example, "Ms. Dr. Prof. Jones".

Comment: @JohnLawler My advisor probably cares about this even less than I do.  I'm not talking about academic writing, I was just wondering about general practices and why the convention outside of academia seems to be different than that in academia, though I may be wrong of course.

Comment: Virtually all academic conventions are meant to separate academics from non-. And most of them are also meant to separate one mob of academics from another. That's one of the major purposes of linguistic conventions. See sociolinguistics.

Comment: @ThePhoton When I said that "anybody who teaches at a university ***is*** a professor" I didn't distinguish between their title and their form of address. It will be one or the other. Whether the person wants to be *called* that is a different matter. That's why you need to ask them, or listen to what they say to the class. Maybe a particularly eccentric teacher wants to be called "Pudding Head." But *professor* will never be wrong in the sense of that person's *role*. Nor will *doctor* ever be wrong as a *title* if they happen to have a PhD.

Comment: @JasonBassford, you bolded the word "is". A post-doc who teaches a class is not a professor. An instructor hired to teach a class but not on the tenure track is not a professor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question arises because English language, unlike, say, German, is generally not hospitable to more than one title being used before a person's name (either the full name or the surname). That means that, if a person holds more than one title, we have to choose which one to use. Normally, one would use the highest one, because the use of a particular title conversationally implicates that the person does not hold a higher one, and so may be mildly insulting to a person who does in fact hold a higher title. (Of course, if the person, out of modesty or friendliness, tells us to use a lower one, or to dispense with the titles altogether, that trumps the general rules of the language.)

When the titles that a person holds do not belong to the same hierarchy, it may, however, not be immediately obvious which one is higher. This is the case with *professor* and *doctor*: the former is bestowed on one by the university where one is employed, while the latter represents an academic degree, which one has independently of one's employment. The two titles thus belong to different dimensions, so to speak.

Nowadays, most universities would not even consider somebody for a job that carries the title of a professor, if the person does not hold a doctorate. On the other hand, there are quite a few people with doctoral degrees who do not have such jobs. Because of this, in most academic settings, *professor* is regarded as the higher title, and is thus used for all those who actually hold it, while *doctor* is used only for those who do not. In such settings, *doctor* would conversationally implicate, although it wouldn't logically imply, that the person is not a professor.

It is true that North American university students will usually use *professor* for anybody who teaches a course, but that is because they are not (and there is no reason why they should be) familiar with the subtleties of the hierarchy.

But although *professor* is generally regarded as a higher title than *doctor*, there could be some settings where it's the other way round. There are some institutions that will readily give the title of, say, an adjunct professor to a businessperson (without a doctoral degree) who teaches one course in its business school. At such a place *doctor* could be regarded as the higher title, as it is an indication of one's being a career academic.

Professors who are also medical doctors are generally addressed as doctors within the settings in which they actually attend to patients, presumably because *professor* could be confusing to the patients.

Although everybody whose title contains the word *professor* is now regarded as entitled to be addressed as a professor, in the past, until half a century or so ago, the standard practice in North America was to reserve that form of address for those who were full professors, and to not use it for those who were associate or assistant professors; they were addressed by whatever title they otherwise held, which was usually *doctor*. This old practice made North American forms of address roughly parallel to the forms of address based on the traditional British system of academic ranks, in which only the most senior academics hold the title of a professor (with others being readers, senior lecturers, lecturers). At that time it was not uncommon for North American students to address those who were teaching them as 'doctor so-and-so'. It is possible that the journalistic practice that the OP observed echoes that old practice.

Answer (score 0):

- Doctor is an indication that the person holds a degree of Ph.D or D.Phil, awarded (except in the case of an honorary degree) as the result of examined research.
- Professor was in English speaking countries, in the main, a job description. In Britain the head of a university department, in the US it indicated an academic post in a university. (It could also be a title acknowledging distinction.)

Therefore, if a newspaper article refers to a scientist whose academic position is unknown to the journalist, Dr is the safe bet, especially as the person may work in a research institute. Several Nobel laureates of my acquaintance come to mind in this respect. Also, the association of “doctor” with medicine (however false it may be) has an appeal to the readers of newspapers, whereas “professor” recalls Tom Lehrer’s “ivy-covered professors in ivy-covered halls”.

Comment: @jsw29 Ok. I’ll take that out. There are other journalistic considerations and dimensions, but tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

Almost all professors are doctors. Therefore they may be accurately addressed as either "doctor" or "professor".

But of course it's usually considered more respectful to address someone by their most prestigious title, so within an academic context we more often call professors "professor" rather than merely "doctor". And of course we call post-docs "doctor" because they have achieved that title, but not any higher one (in academic terms).

I don't know the motivation for the New York Times decision to refer to professors as "doctor", but it isn't wrong to use that address (assuming they have a doctorate).